# Azure Active Directory txt record not applying

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Active Directory initial domain `example.onmicrosoft.com` and would like to change the txt. record I tried for a custom domain. I changed my ns. record everything is fine but for the `example.onmicrosoft.com` not working

Answer (score 0):

Every new Azure AD tenant comes with an initial domain name, .onmicrosoft.com. You can't change or delete the initial domain name, but you can add your organization's names. Kindly check the below documents and see if it helps .

[Document 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-with-domains/find-and-fix-issues?view=o365-worldwide) , [Document 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain)

Comment: yes but i need to change txt record for that .onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: Generally you cannot change the txt record for the .onmicrosoft.com .

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_3xRLv9I8Hrf9if3&Q_CHL=gl
>